# Multiple types of MySQL query within same page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

As I was learning PHP I used forms and posts across multiple pages, for example: a form on addpage.php would point to another page which would execute MySQL code using the post values from addpage as variables.

This served me well for making the code work, but now I have implemented the code all within the same page using `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` then running the SQL code.

On my pages which display database info, I have javascript buttons which currently direct the user to various pages and append a $_GET on to the url with the id of the row. an example of this is:

```
function deleteRow(id) {
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")
    if (r==true)
        {
            location.href = "deleterow.php?id=" + id;
        }
}
```

deleterow.php simply grabs the `$id = $_GET['id']` and runs a delete query with a `WHERE id = $id`. Not the most elegant solution but it works. (NB. this isnt the actual code i used, just saved time writing this way)

If the buttons were forms rather than javascript buttons I know that I could give the submit buttons specific names e.g. `if(isset($_POST['delete'])) { run delete code..` but this would cause layout issues.

What I want to know is, if there is method for integrating this into a page, rather than having a seperate PHP page for deleting and things? My current method works fine for the purpose, but in the interests of learning i'd like to keep the number of pages in the site to a minimum, without pages with just one block of code in them with redirects.

Comment: AJAX? That would seem the most appropriate way of handling it.

Comment: AJAX is not a language but a technique that combines a serverside language (php/mysql) with a client language (javascript) to send messages to a server without the need to refresh the page. Specifically in your case you can send a post request, listen for a response and load an output inside a HTML/XML tag (eg DIV) without a redirect. There are tons of tutorials out there

Comment: @AlanKaelBall Thanks, I've done some searching but I think I'll avoid AJAX. I'm looking for a more simple solution, AJAX looks to be way beyond my level. I'm confident I could find working code with it, that I don't understand at all, but I'm just trying to learn PHP/MySQL mainly at the moment, with a smidgy bit of Javascript for some basic design and validation purposes. If it isn't possible then my current solution will suffice.